# .NET List<T> Concat vs AddRange

Tags: .net, linq, list, extension-methods

What is the difference between the [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) functions on a generic List? Is one recommended over the other?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

They have totally different semantics.

AddRange modifies the list by adding the other items to it.

Concat returns a new sequence containing the list and the other items, without modifying the list.

Choose whichever one has the semantics you want.

Comment: So ion a tight loop, it would be much better to use add range so not as to lose performance due to all the internal newing and pounding the GC?

Comment: @GregBeech I know this is a very old comment, you are wrong. First of all, deferred execution has nothing to do with performance. Second of all, you mixed the two (even though you said it correctly in the actual reply). Concat creates a new object in memory without modifying the other two sequences, which is why it is slower than AddRange. When dealing with small sequences, the difference is not noticeable, but when dealing with large collections, AddRange must be used as it is significantly faster (unless you need to keep the two sequences unmodified for some reason).

Comment: @johnc you are correct, AddRange is faster because it does not create a whole new object, however, the speed difference is negligible when dealing with small sequences.

Comment: I’m wrong about performance even though I didn’t mention performance? ‍♂️

Answer (score 47):

The big difference is that `AddRange` mutates that list against which it is called whereas `Concat` creates a new List.  Hence they have different uses.

Also `Concat` is an extension method that applies to any `IEnumerable<T>` and returns an `IEnumerable<T>` you need a `.ToList()` to result in a new List.

If you want to extend the content of an existing list use `AddRange`.

If you are creating a new list from two `IEnumerable<T>` sources then use `Concat` with `.ToList`.  This has the quality that it does not mutate either of sources.

If you only ever need to enumerate the contents of two Lists (or any other IEnumerable) then simply use `Concat` each time, this has the advantage of not actually allocating new memory to hold the unified list.

Comment: +1, Indeed, if you forget to 'tolist', concat silently does nothing

Answer (score 11):

I found this interesting article talking about the difference between these 2 structures and comparing their performance...

The main idea is that AddRange is way much faster when its about big size collections.

Here is the [Link](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/232514-collection-type-result-whats-faster-ilist-add-or-ienumerable-concat)

Hope this helps,

Comment: I've done a test comparing `Concat` and `AddRange` with a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` with 1000 elements, concatenated/added 100 times, and `AddRange` was extremely faster. The results were these: `AddRange` 13 ms, `Concat().ToList()` 16,000 ms, and `Concat` on an `IEnumerable` doing only the `ToList` at the end: 2,700 ms.