# Which is faster: Union or Concat?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, union, concatenation

Which is faster: `Union` or `Concat`?

I don't care about the order of the elements.

[Enumerable.Union Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union)

[Enumerable.Concat Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat)

Comment: Try it both ways. Get out a stopwatch. Then you'll know. Performance "analysis" based on *guesswork*, no matter how educated,  is not actually useful as a basis to make *engineering* decisions.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`Union` removes duplicates. `Concat` does not.

So, they produce different results if the sources either contain any items in common, or have any internal duplicates.

If you can guarantee there are no duplicates, or if there are few and you don't care about having them in your output, `Concat` will be faster since there's no need to test each value against what has already been yielded.

However, if there are many duplicates and you don't need them, the extra processing in `Union` to remove the dupes may be offset by the savings in your code that consumes the results.

Answer (score 10):

Do you only care about execution speed? How long does it take you to process an element when you receive it?

`Concat` is simpler - it doesn't need to perform any processing itself, or buffer the results that it's already returned. However, it will produce more results if there are any elements in the intersection. If you're going to take a long time to process each result, `Concat` may end up *effectively* being slower.

Comment: In my case, I'll use a Distinct() in the end, which favors the use of Union I think.

Comment: If you use Union then you don't need to call Distinct afterwards anyway.

Comment: Union removes duplicates between the lists, but if the first list  has duplicates within itself those will not be removed by union.  So - Distinct might still need to be called, depending on circumstances.

Comment: @DavidB: That's not true (i'm not sure if it was sometime). `Union` will remove dups even if they are duplicate only in one of both lists.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Confirmed! (with a quick console app) :)

Answer (score 3):

What was said above is right. **Here is just a little addition for some special cases**:

If you have to concatenate for example two lists and **if you need full speed, consider using `yield`**. Of course this is a lot less flexible and comfortable than `Union` or `Concat` in Linq. Therefore it makes only sense in special cases.

This property for example will provide the same as `List1.Concat(List2)`

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> AllObjects
{
    get
    {
        foreach (MyObject o1 in List1)
            yield return o1;

        foreach (MyObject o2 in List2)
            yield return o2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Concat` exactly does it the way you show it in the example (see: [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#800)). So there is no need to implement it by your own.