# Filling an object list with multiple queries

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object model that I build with composition and that looks like this:

```
MyModel{
  public int ModelID {get;set;}
  public List<OtherModel1> ListOfOtherModel {get;set;}
  public List<OtherModeln> ListOfOtherModels {get;set;}
  ...
}
```

I have a linq-to-sql query that return a list of ModelID and I pass this collection as the input paramater for other queries to populate the lists of OtherModels object; these objects are related to MyModel through the ModelID. When these queries end (I have 9 queries), I end up with 10 lists.

I'm passing those 10 lists (ListOfMyModel and the 9 others : ListOfOtherModel1, ListOfOtherModels...) to another function that'll build a collection of MyModel by looping throught the ListOfMyModel and querying each of the other lists to see if they contain lists with the same ModelID.

As I'm doing all that, I'm just wondering if there's an easier/faster/better way to do it. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered using an Interface for your generic type on List<OfModelN> with List<IModelN> and then injecting all results into one list? Not clear from your example the association the results in the lists have the model.

Comment: Can you show me with some code what it could look like?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "querying each of the other lists to see if they contain lists"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have a common base class, you cast the collection then perform a union with each of them, before performing the query.

For example, assuming `Derived1` and `Derived2` have the common base class `CommonBaseClass`

```
 IEnumerable<CommonBaseClass> Merge(List<Derived1> derived1list, List<Dervived2> derived2list){
      return derived1list.Cast<CommonBaseClass>().Union(derived2list.Cast<CommonBaseClass>());
 }
```

So, you could just merge all the lists and then perform the query on the big `CommonBaseClass` collection instead of the querying each individually then joining them.

I think this is the kind of thing you are looking for, but your question wasn't extraordinarily clear.  If you post some code, it would be easier to help you.

It also seemed like you may be looking for the `SelectMany` extension method, but I'm not sure because the language was unclear.

Comment: What is the difference between Union<>() and Concat<>() in this respect?

Comment: Union removes duplicates. Concat does not.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337699/which-is-faster-union-or-concat-c-linq