# Merge two lists

Tags: c#, .net, list, merge, compare

I have two lists of tests which some of them contain properties (key,value).
Lets call them `list-A` & `list-B`.

I want to do the following (on `list-B` only):

1) add test that `list-A` has and `list-B` doesn't (with all properties).

2) add property that `list-A` has and `list-B` doesn't

3) remove property that `list-B` has and `list-A` doesn't

how can I do that in C# with less than 4/5 for loops?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/merge-two-object-lists-with-linq

Answer (score 0):

If I understant your problem, only two loops are necessary... But what is a property and what is a test in your case? The key is the test and the value is a property?

```
foreach(type key in a.keys)
{
  //a1 I think. adds a key not in b
  if(!b.ContainsKey(key))
  {
    b.Add(key, a[key]);
  }
  else
  {
    //a2 I think... I suppose that the value is a list of properties
    foreach(type prop in a[key])
    {
      if(!b[key].Contains(prop))
      {
        b[key].Add(prop);
      }
    }
  }
}
```