# Comparing two lists for duplicates in either of them in C#

Tags: c#

I have two Lists like so:

```
List<EmpData> colExistingEmpData;
List<EmpData> colExternalEmpData;
```

Each of them will have employee records that have the same Id.
I know this sounds wierd but that's a real situation I am in right now!

For every employee in colExternalEmpData based on EmpId a check is made on colExistingEmpData

```
foreach (EmpData employee in colExternalEmpData)
{
  var queryResult = colExistingEmpData.FindAll(thisEmployee => thisEmployee.Id == employee.Id);

  if(querResult.count == 0)
  {
    // Mark as INSERT
  } 
  else if(querResult.count == 1)
  {
    // Mark as UPDATE
  }
  else // queryResult is more than 1
  {
    // data is duplicated mark as IGNORE
  }

  analysedData.Add(employee);
```

This works fine when colExistingEmpData has no duplicated value for the 'Id'

When there are duplicates in colExternalEmpData, meaning if two employees have same 'ID' as 123 the above code will still mark the existing employee with 123 id as update because it finds an exact match in colExistingEmpData provided colExistingEmpData has just one reocrd with that Id.

Is there a way in which an employee record can be marked as 'IGNORE' when it's repeated in either of the sources?

I can't use a Dictionary object, I had used it before but the powers that be didn't like the idea.

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean with "mark as IGNORE" ? Why cant you have an HashSet with all the Ids that are duplicates? Also your query will run two times here. Use ToList to only run it once ;)

Comment: is this ur exact code? `FindAll` returns a list, not an integer, doesnt it?

Comment: *I had used it before but the powers that be didn't like the idea*. That's something new I must admit. Do your peers prefer apps to be slow and hanging also? Dictionary would yield fastest results in this case (at least asymptotically).

Comment: @Groo you are very generous when using the words slow and hanging for my peers, they prefer in giving marching orders instead.

Comment: @Groo, I have to say I understand where he's coming from. I don't know if you've ever worked in an extremely large organization, but there are things that just aren't allowed, regardless. Those things generally don't make sense, it's really more about somebody flaunting the position they have in the organization than anything else. They don't understand it - so they quash it - it makes them feel bigger and badder. Big organization politics - that's it.

Comment: @Michael: I guess you're right, I've had the luck of working at places where good programming practices (well, common sense at least) are encouraged. If that's a big bad organization, then I would probably be compelled to create a big bad presentation comparing performance of a list lookup vs a dictionary lookup. Dogmatic rules such as this can only lower effectivenes and ultimately lower the product quality.

Comment: @Groo, if I had a nickle for every time I've felt the same way and then realized you can't change things with rational - I'd be rich. I've worked in very small companies and I've worked in very large companies (from 25 to 25,000) and in the very large companies you must play the political game to get to the top (where you can make decisions like that) but then you must play politics to stay on top (which keep you from making decisions like that). Man, it's tough! LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider just adding a processed list to the equation:

```
List<int> processed = new List<int>();
```

and then at the top of the loop add this code:

```
if (processed.Contains(employee.Id)) { continue; }
processed.Add(employee.Id);
```

and so you do that **before** you check the other list. It's the first thing you do because you don't really care if it's already been processed.

Comment: This would be equivalent to just put continue; in his last else. I think he wants to mark the duplicates for some reason, not just skip them.

Comment: @Evelie, the issue is that the employee shows up twice in the first list, the one being iterated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your problem correctly, You can always sort your ExternalList, by the employeeID, and then instead of using a Foreach loop, just use a while loop and skip employees while the id is the same.

This is +- how the code should look, reduced to integers:

```
List<int> external = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 3 };
List<int> internalList = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 5, 3 };
external.Sort();
int index = 0;
int item = -1;
while (index < external.Count)
{
    if (external[index] != item)
    {
       item = external[index];
       internalList.FindAll(t => t == item);
    }
    index++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this would help, but why not merge the two lists, and remove duplicates :-

```
var mergedList = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

You should check out this Question :-

[Create a list from two object lists with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/merge-two-object-lists-with-linq)

Comment: Essentially the OP needs to know, row by row, how to process it. Joining the two lists, though would get rid of the duplicates, wouldn't really address the need to know how to process each row based on its existence in the second list.

Comment: It's took me 5 attempts to understand that Question lol, i take your point, your correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be overriding the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and using `.Distinct()`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.90%29.aspx)