# LINQ merge into single record with unique description

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to filter a list on the basis of a criteria and then trying to combine that criteria into a single record.
I'm able to this by using this approach:

```
Dim PortfolioSAA_Bonds = PortfolioSAA.Where(Function(x) x.Description = "Australian Fixed Interest" OrElse x.Description = "International Fixed Interest").ToList()

Dim tmpSAAPortfolio As New SaaPortfolioReportModel
tmpSAAPortfolio.Description = "Bonds"
tmpSAAPortfolio.RiskProfileAllocation = PortfolioSAA_Bonds.Sum(Function(x) x.RiskProfileAllocation)
tmpSAAPortfolio.SAAVariation = PortfolioSAA_Bonds.Sum(Function(x) x.SAAVariation)
tmpSAAPortfolio.ActualSAA = PortfolioSAA_Bonds.Sum(Function(x) x.ActualSAA)
```

and then

```
PortfolioSAACustom = PortfolioSAA.Except(PortfolioSAA_Bonds).ToList()
PortfolioSAACustom.Add(tmpSAAPortfolio)
```

Is this possible to use a single LINQ statement to filter the above values on into a single record with a unique description (like I'm using 'Bonds') above.

I tried using the following but it didn't work:

```
   Dim ttt = From j In PortfolioSAA
              Where j.Description = "Australian Fixed Interest" OrElse j.Description = "International Fixed Interest"
              Group By x = New With {Key .Description = "Bonds", Key .RiskProfileAllocation = j.RiskProfileAllocation, Key .SAAVariation = j.SAAVariation, Key .ActualSAA = j.ActualSAA} Into g = Group
              Select New SaaPortfolioReportModel With {
                                                                        .Description = "Bonds",
                                                                        .RiskProfileAllocation = g.Sum(Function(r) r.RiskProfileAllocation),
                                                                        .SAAVariation = g.Sum(Function(r) r.SAAVariation),
                                                                        .ActualSAA = g.Sum(Function(r) r.SAAVariation)
                                                                     }
```

Have tried [s1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/merge-two-object-lists-with-linq) and [s2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/merge-two-object-lists-with-linq) but could'nt get the result.

Comment: Where is `g` in your linq statement is coming from?

Comment: That's `IGrouping`, as OP is running an Aggregation function