# Merge 2 dynamic table data with same ID or name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 table having data as dt1 and dt2 on  the basis of id

```
id column1 column2
1   abc

id column1 column2
1           def
```

How should I can make it as

```
id column1 column2
1     abc     def
```

**I need a c# code**

Comment: i guess linq queries can help you

Comment: how can u give me one example?

Comment: you could have asked that without downvoting

Comment: Duplicate as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/merge-two-object-lists-with-linq

Comment: this things are done in list format, for this i 1st convert my table to list format, I have lacs of record, on converting it will take time

Answer (score 1):

Answer taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2767742/2537148

```
var query = database.dt1// your starting point - table in the "from" statement
       .Join(database.dt2, // the source table of the inner join
          post => dt1.id,        // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
          meta => dt2.id,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
          (dt1, dt2) => new { Dt1= dt1, Dt2= dt2}); // selection
```

Comment: My actual 2 table name are as dtlocalpath and dtlocalinnerpath but on writing statement as database.dtlocalpath  its showing error

Comment: U mean i need to take dataContext?

Comment: database is has to be defined first as your database connection. If it is called dataContext in your case, yes.