# How do I merge two seperate '.ToList()"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, linq

There are several posts where people are asking [how to merge generic lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/create-a-list-from-two-object-lists-with-linq).
However, in my case I have two seperate linq statements where I am returning two separate database results `.ToList()`

```
var appleList = (from al in db.Apples where al.Id == id select al).ToList();
var bananaList = (from bl in db.Bananas where bl.Id == id select bl).ToList();
```

I tried merging these list like so:

```
appleList.Concat(bananaList);
```

but this causes the following error:

**'List' does not contain a definition for 'Concat'**

How do I combine these two `.ToList()`?

Comment: `appleList.AddRange(bananaList);`, try this

Comment: when I do that it says `cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<ProjectName.Models.Bananas> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Model>`

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty Presumbably `Apple` and `Banana` are different types. You can't add instances of two different types into the same List, unless the List is some common supertype.

Comment: @Skullomania, My bad, I didn't see they are of 2 different types. You cannot merge in your case, as they are of different types

Answer (score 0):

Create a fruit class and derive both apples and bananas from it.

https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/B/base_class.html