# How do I go about converting my List to an IEnumerable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, linq, stored-procedures, ienumerable

I have a list that I created from a SQL query and another list using linq:

```
var List1 = db.Database.SqlQuery<Apples>("spAllApples AppleNum", param).ToList();
var List2 = (from r in db.bananas where r.bananaNum == id).ToList();
```

The problem I have ran into is that one shows up as a list and the other as an IEnumerable when I try to combine them using `.Concat()` as well as `AddRange` [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488054/merge-two-or-more-lists-into-one-in-c-sharp-net).

I have also tried doing this:

```
IEnumerable<Apples> List3 = List1.ToList();
List3.Concat(List2);
```

and was met with the error

**IEnumerable<Apple> does not contain a definition for 'Concat' or 'AddRange'**

Due to permissions, I do not have access to write stored procs for `List2` which would have been the other simple fix. How do I go about combining these two lists?

Comment: Are you missing `using System.Linq;` ? Also , the first part of your message is confusing because the code is invalid and because you don't actually say what happens when you try to combine them using .Concat() .

Comment: `List1` is already a `List`. And as `List` implements the `IEnumerable` interface, you can just use the `Concat` extension method on `IEnumerable` and do `var List3 = List1.Concat(List2).ToList()`. But this still won't work, because you can't add bananas to a list of apples. Same as you asked in this question a few hours ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970288/how-do-i-merge-two-seperate-tolist