# Joining two lists together

Tags: c#

If I have two lists of type string (or any other type), what is a quick way of joining the two lists?

The order should stay the same. Duplicates should be removed (though every item in both links are unique). I didn't find much on this when googling and didn't want to implement any .NET interfaces for speed of delivery.

Comment: Does order matter?  Do you want to retain duplicates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do you concatenate Lists in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042219/how-do-you-concatenate-lists-in-c)*.

Answer (score 749, accepted):

You could try:

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
List<string> b = new List<string>();

a.AddRange(b);
```

[MSDN page for `AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)

This preserves the order of the lists, but it doesn't remove any duplicates (which [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) would do).

This does change list `a`. If you wanted to preserve the original lists then you should use [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) (as pointed out in the other answers):

```
var newList = a.Concat(b);
```

This returns an `IEnumerable` as long as `a` is not null.

Comment: No one's really gone into when to use which method. AddRange edits a list in place, adding the second list to it (as if you called .Add(foo) a bunch of times). The Concat and Union extension methods don't change the original list. They lazily construct a new IEnumerable and won't even access the original list members unless necessary. As noted, Union removes duplicates while the others don't.

Comment: Does anyone know what is the complexity of this method? (It is so shame Microsoft doesn't supply this important information as part of their MSDN)

Comment: I recommend you check this good comparison of he various approaches. Also show some performance analysis of various options: [Merge Collections](https://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2012/10/18/merge-collections-without-duplicates-in-c)

Comment: This works perfectly. Was using concat() on more than half a million items, which took several minutes. This approach takes less than 5 seconds.

Comment: hi.. is concat function return null if the list is empty?

Comment: and second question.. is concat works for object? not only int or string..?

Answer (score 141):

The way with the least space overhead is to use the Concat extension method.

```
var combined = list1.Concat(list2);
```

It creates an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` which will enumerate the elements of list1 and list2 in that order.

Comment: remember to `using System.Linq;` to be able to use Concat

Answer (score 49):

The [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) method might address your needs.  You didn't specify whether order or duplicates was important.

Take two IEnumerables and perform a union as seen here:

```
int[] ints1 = { 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 9, 3, 7 };
int[] ints2 = { 8, 3, 6, 4, 4, 9, 1, 0 };

IEnumerable<int> union = ints1.Union(ints2);

// yields { 5, 3, 9, 7, 8, 6, 4, 1, 0 }
```

Answer (score 27):

Something like this:

```
firstList.AddRange (secondList);
```

Or, you can use the 'Union' extension method that is defined in System.Linq.
With 'Union', you can also specify a comparer, which can be used to specify whether an item should be unioned or not.

Like this:

```
List<int> one = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> second=new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 6 };

var result = one.Union (second, new EqComparer ());

foreach( int x in result )
{
    Console.WriteLine (x);
}
Console.ReadLine ();

#region IEqualityComparer<int> Members
public class EqComparer : IEqualityComparer<int>
{
    public bool Equals( int x, int y )
    {
        return x == y;
    }

    public int GetHashCode( int obj )
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode ();
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: +1 for use of an EqualityComparer!  I was able to use it for better handling of my lists of custom objects.

Answer (score 21):

```
targetList = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();
```

It's working fine I think so. As previously said, Concat returns a new sequence and while converting the result to List, it does the job perfectly. Implicit conversions may fail sometimes when using the AddRange method.

Answer (score 14):

If some item(s) exist in both lists you may use

```
var all = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3) ... Concat(listN).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

As long as they are of the same type, it's very simple with AddRange:

```
list2.AddRange(list1);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var bigList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
    .Concat(new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 })
    .ToList(); /// yields { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
```

Comment: I like this too. Very simple. Thanks.

Comment: I like this because it doesn't mutate either list.

Comment: Is this like Union All? Or not? What if number 1 exist on all of lists?

Comment: `Concat` is more/less "Union All"

Answer (score 6):

The [AddRange method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)

```
aList.AddRange( anotherList );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("dot");
list1.Add("net");

List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
list2.Add("pearls");
list2.Add("!");

var result = list1.Concat(list2);
```

Answer (score 3):

one way: `List.AddRange()` depending on the types?

Answer (score 2):

One way, I haven't seen mentioned that can be a bit more robust, particularly if you wanted to alter each element in some way (e.g. you wanted to `.Trim()` all of the elements.

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
List<string> b = new List<string>();
// ...
b.ForEach(x=>a.Add(x.Trim()));
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class ProductA
{ 
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Code { get; set; }
}

public class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProductA>
{

public bool Equals(ProductA x, ProductA y)
{
    //Check whether the objects are the same object. 
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

    //Check whether the products' properties are equal. 
    return x != null && y != null && x.Code.Equals(y.Code) && x.Name.Equals(y.Name);
    }

public int GetHashCode(ProductA obj)
{
    //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
    int hashProductName = obj.Name == null ? 0 : obj.Name.GetHashCode();

    //Get hash code for the Code field. 
    int hashProductCode = obj.Code.GetHashCode();

    //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
    return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
}
}


    ProductA[] store1 = { new ProductA { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                   new ProductA { Name = "orange", Code = 4 } };

    ProductA[] store2 = { new ProductA { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                   new ProductA { Name = "lemon", Code = 12 } };
```

//Get the products from the both arrays
//excluding duplicates.

```
IEnumerable<ProductA> union =
  store1.Union(store2);

foreach (var product in union)
    Console.WriteLine(product.Name + " " + product.Code);

/*
    This code produces the following output:

    apple 9
    orange 4
    lemon 12
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

The two options I use are:

```
list1.AddRange(list2);
```

or

```
list1.Concat(list2);
```

However I noticed as I used that when using the `AddRange` method with a recursive function, that calls itself very often I got an SystemOutOfMemoryException because the maximum number of dimensions was reached.

(Message Google Translated)
*The array dimensions exceeded the supported range.*

Using `Concat` solved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to test how `Union` works with the default comparer on overlapping collections of reference type objects.

My object is:

```
class MyInt
{
    public int val;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return val.ToString();
    }
}
```

My test code is:

```
MyInt[] myInts1 = new MyInt[10];
MyInt[] myInts2 = new MyInt[10];
int overlapFrom = 4;
Console.WriteLine("overlapFrom: {0}", overlapFrom);

Action<IEnumerable<MyInt>, string> printMyInts = (myInts, myIntsName) => Console.WriteLine("{2} ({0}): {1}", myInts.Count(), string.Join(" ", myInts), myIntsName);

for (int i = 0; i < myInts1.Length; i++)
    myInts1[i] = new MyInt { val = i };
printMyInts(myInts1, nameof(myInts1));

int j = 0;
for (; j + overlapFrom < myInts1.Length; j++)
    myInts2[j] = myInts1[j + overlapFrom];
for (; j < myInts2.Length; j++)
    myInts2[j] = new MyInt { val = j + overlapFrom };
printMyInts(myInts2, nameof(myInts2));

IEnumerable<MyInt> myUnion = myInts1.Union(myInts2);
printMyInts(myUnion, nameof(myUnion));

for (int i = 0; i < myInts2.Length; i++)
    myInts2[i].val += 10;
printMyInts(myInts2, nameof(myInts2));
printMyInts(myUnion, nameof(myUnion));

for (int i = 0; i < myInts1.Length; i++)
    myInts1[i].val = i;
printMyInts(myInts1, nameof(myInts1));
printMyInts(myUnion, nameof(myUnion));
```

The output is:

```
overlapFrom: 4
myInts1 (10): 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
myInts2 (10): 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
myUnion (14): 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
myInts2 (10): 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
myUnion (14): 0 1 2 3 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
myInts1 (10): 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
myUnion (14): 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 20 21 22 23
```

So, everything works fine.