# Non-standard joining of two lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two lists: `list1` and `list2`. I want to join the lists in a way that the values in `list1` should not be affected, even if it contains duplicate values. However, when appending values from `list2` the duplicate values should not be removed.

I had tried `Union`, which will distinct all the values and eliminate my repeated values in `list1`.

For example

```
list1 = [a, b, c, c, d, e] 
list2 = [a,c,f,g] 
my required solution 
list3=[a, b, c, c, d, e, f, g]
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code so everyone can have a look at where you're going wrong

Comment: [`.Concat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528171/joining-two-lists-together

Can you clarify your question? I can't seem to pick it up.

Comment: for example

list1 = [a, b, c, c, d, e]
list2 = [a,c,f,g]

my required solution 

list3=[a, b, c, c, d, e, f, g]

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Concat will just join two list. I have Specific requirement

Comment: It really helps if you just try to think of a way to do that on paper or just describe the algorithm, e.g. *I start with copying the first list. Then for each item in the second list I do ....*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var MyList = List1.Concat(List2.Except(List1).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list3 = list1.ToList();
foreach (var val in list2)
{
    if (!list3.Contains(val))
        list3.Add(val);
}
```

This would give you a new list with all the values from list1 and list2.

Comment: Which is not what the author of the question wants.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use something like this

```
var list1 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 3}; 
var list2 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3};
var list3 = list1.Concat(list2.Except(list1)); // 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5
```