# How to Join two list in C#?

Tags: c#, list, join

[I want this output in list3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urgje.png)I have two `list` with Custom Data Type

```
list1 = {A, B, C, D} 
 [enter image description here][1]
list2 ={ X, A, B, Y}
```

Then I need to remove A, B from `list1` and Add A and B from `list2` with list1.

```
list3 = { A(list2), B(list2), C(list1), D(list1)}



See Above Image, I want those items whose ts_key = 0 and if those records are already in list then get ts_key <> 0 for repeated record
```

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528171/joining-two-lists-together

Comment: What is the data type of your elements A,B,C,D?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Explain the conditions in English, then it's trivial to write it in code. _Why_ should A and B be taken from list2 and not list1? Do you also need to _remove_ the items from list1 and list2, or do you just want a new collection? What is the difference between list1's A and list2's A? Why do you want to take the latter?

Comment: @Sefe I
 try intersect but it is not working

Comment: explain more about your `Custom Type`.. how do you uniquely identify A and B?

Comment: what is the difference between `A` of `list1` and `A` of `list2`?

Comment: Use AddRange() method to add an array to current list.  List<CustomType> list3 = new List<CustomType>(); list3.AddRange(list1); list3.AddRange(list2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first join your two lists. That gives you exactly the intersection of two collections:

```
var lst = list1.Join(list2, tr => tr.tr_key, tr => tr.tr_key, (x,y)=>y).ToList();
```

After that you could add to this list all the values from the first list, that are not in the second list. For that you actually need an EqualiyComparer  (I assume name of your class as `tr`):

```
public class tr_comparer: IEqualityComparer<tr>
{
    public bool Equals(tr x, tr y)
    {
        return x.tr_key == y.tr_key;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(tr obj)
    {
        return obj.tr_key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

After you define a comparer you could execute `Except`:

```
lst.AddRange(list1.Except(list2, new tr_comparer()));
```

Comment: Thank You Bro... It Works...!

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

This may help ..try it

Comment: It is not union operation, it is intersect operation, but common element from list2 merged with list1 and remove common elements from list1

Comment: This is close, except it will also add elements in `list2` that are not in `list1`, where OP just wants to replace instances of objects in `list1` with their `list2` counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<T> list3=new List<T>
foreach(var item in list1)
{
   if(list2.Contains(item))
   {
      list3.Add(list2.First(x=>x.id==item.id)) //considering id is key
   }
   else
   {
      list3.Add(item);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to pick the common elements from `list2` and everything else from `list1`. It sounds like you might be able to pull this off if you perform both a Difference *and* an Intersection

```
var list3 = new List<CustomType>();
list3.AddRange(list1.Except(list2));
list3.AddRange(list2.Intersect(list1));
```