# C# Add List To List

Tags: c#

I have some ViewModel like this.

```
public class ModelResult
{
   public string NAME { get; set; }
   public List<DataPointVM> RESULTs { get; set; }
}
public class DataPointVM
{
   private float v1;
   private float v2;
   public DataPointVM(float v1, float v2)
   {
      this.TIME = v1;
      this.VALUE = v2;
   }

   public float TIME { get; set; }
   public float VALUE { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have a list key

```
List<string> parameterList = new List<string>(new string[] {
   "Jhon",
   "Andy",
   "Ivan",
   "Erick",
});
```

DataPoint ViewModel will store data like `[{"Car1":"Bentley"},{"Car2":"Ferarri"}]`

I try with this code but the result is only display last key (Erick)
example:`[{"NAME":"ERICK","RESULTs":[{"car1":"xxx"},{"car2":"yyy"}]}]`

```
ModelResult mdlres = new ModelResult();
            for (index=0;index<parameterList.Count();index++)
            {
                List<DataPointVM> points = new List<DataPointVM>();
                    mdlres.NAME = parameterList[index];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        points.Add(new ViewModels.DataPointVM(tVal[i], rVal[i]));
                    }
                    mdlres.RESULTs = points.ToList();
            }
            return mdlres;
```

I want to get all listkey with the details.

Comment: Where did tVal and rVal come from?  Do you have multiple copies of those for the different names?

Comment: `mdlres.RESULTs = points.ToList();` should be `mdlres.RESULTs.AddRange(points);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining two lists together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528171/joining-two-lists-together)

Comment: Your `ModelResult` only has a single name in it.  Do you want multiple names in there?  Does each name need its own set of data points?  You either need to return a List<ModelResult>, or add another layer here.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I have write the solution here. https://pastebin.com/uB2n6X3C

I should put ```ModelResult mdlres = new ModelResult();``` inside first loop and ```newList.mresult.Add(mdlres);```

Comment: @HendraSYP if you solved your own problem, can you post it as an answer for others in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for my thread, but I've solve my problem.

```
ModelResult mdlres = new ModelResult(); 
// insert detail into detail list 
// exit loop
newList.mresult.Add(mdlres); create collection of mdlres
```

My code have been published here:
https://pastebin.com/uB2n6X3C