# Joining two lists of different types but same superclass

Tags: c#, list

I want to know if I can merge together two lists of different types but both having the same `super` class

```
public class A : super {}
public class B : super {}


ListA<super> ListA = new List<super>();

ListA<B> ListA = new List<B>();
```

I want to combine these two lists to something like:

```
List <super> ListCombined = new List <super>();
```

also, note that `A` and `B` have the same `super` class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining two lists together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528171/joining-two-lists-together)

Answer (score 3):

You can try *Linq*:

```
   ListCombined = ListA
     .OfType<super>()
     .Concat(ListB)
     .ToList();
```

Or `AddRange` (no Linq solution):

```
   List<super> ListCombined = new List<super>();

   ListCombined.AddRange(ListA);
   ListCombined.AddRange(ListB);
```

Comment: @xdtTransform: you are quite right, but for the sake of *generalization* (when `ListA` items are derived from `super`, if we want to swap `ListA` and `ListB`) let me use `OfType<super>`

Comment: Agree, Comment was a clarification for other, le me rephrase it so it clearer. `List<A>.Concat(List<Super>)` or `List<Super>.Concat(List<A>)` will compile an give an List<Super>. While `List<A>.Concat(List<B>)`  will not work as there is no direct way between A and B, You will need to use `OfType<Super>()` in order to make it work like in the previous exemple.

Answer (score 1):

Possible:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        List<ExtendedCar1> cars1 = new List<ExtendedCar1>{
            new ExtendedCar1{Brand = "Audi", Model = "R8"},
            new ExtendedCar1{Brand = "Bentley", Model = "Azure"}
        };

        List<ExtendedCar2> cars2 = new List<ExtendedCar2>{
            new ExtendedCar2{Brand = "Ferrari", Color ="Red"},
            new ExtendedCar2{Brand = "Maruti", Color ="Saffire Blue"}
        };

        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>(cars1);
        cars.AddRange(cars2);

        foreach(var car in cars){
            Console.WriteLine($"Car Brand: {car.Brand}");
        }

    }

}


public class Car{
   public String Brand {get;set;}    
}

public class ExtendedCar1 : Car {
   public String Model{get;set;}    
}

public class ExtendedCar2: Car {
   public String Color {get;set;}    
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By super I assume you mean base class?

```
public class Parent 
{

   public List<ChildA> ChildListA { get; set;}
   public List<ChildB> ChildListB { get; set;}

}

public class ChildA:Parent
{

}
public class ChildB:Parent
{

}

var parentList= new List<Parent>();

parentList.Add( new Parent() { ChildListA=new List<ChildA>(),  ChildListB=new List<ChildB>()}); 
// assuming parent is not abstract
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple and do just something like this:

```
var ListA = new List<A>();
var ListB = new List<B>();

var ListCombined = new List<Super>(ListA);
ListCombined.AddRange(ListB);
```

or you are also able to do this

```
var ListSuper = new List<Super>();
var ListB = new List<B>();

var ListCombined = new List<Super>(ListB);
ListCombined.AddRange(ListSuper);
```