# C# LINQ Combine values of 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `list` with `tickets` in it:

`TicketID` - `Aantal` (amount) - `ActiePrijs` (price)

For all those `tickets` the `ActiePrijs` (price) is still `empty`. But I also have a `list` with only those `Actieprijs` (prices). It's just a `list of decimals`.

Now I want to put the `first actiePrijs from the decimal list into the ActiePrijs from the first ticket, the second ActiePrijs into the ActiePrijs of the second ticket etc`.

I want to do it using linq method syntax.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide mode details (sample data)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining two lists together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528171/joining-two-lists-together)

Comment: please add the code...

Comment: You're looking for [`Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume tickets & price lists are `tickets` and `price`.

You can use linq like below.

```
tickets = tickets.Select((ticket, index) => new Ticket 
                  { 
                      TicketID = ticket.TicketID,
                      Aantal = ticket.Aantal,
                      ActiePrijs = price[index]
                  })
                  .ToList();
```

Or if you have more `properties` and you do not want to create new object then use like below.

```
tickets = tickets.Select((ticket, index) =>
                  {
                      ticket.ActiePrijs = price[index];
                      return ticket;
                  })
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont show any code, but I thing you want something like this.

```
public class Properties
{
    public int Aantal { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
List<Properties> l = new List<Properties>();
l.Add(new Properties() { Aantal = 1 });
l.Add(new Properties() { Aantal = 2 });
l.Add(new Properties() { Aantal = 3 });
List<int> l2 = new List<int>();
l2.Add(1);
l2.Add(2);
l2.Add(3);
int index = 0;
l.ForEach(x => x.Price = l2[index++]);
```