# is there a way to make multiple data field merge together and become a single List<int>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to make multiple data field merge together and become a single List. There is two array which is

```
int[] QueueNo = {10, 20, 30, 40};
int [] WaitingTime = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

How do I insert this two data into one List
So that I can a `foreach` loop to insert the data into the database

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    ////Code For Create Data
}
```

Comment: `foreach(var item in QueueNo.Concat(WaitingTime))` -> no need to create a list; just enumerate both arrays.

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528171/joining-two-lists-together and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217/merging-two-arrays-in-net

Comment: I doubt OP wants to **append** one list to the other, but create one containing the analogous elements from both lists.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay If let say I had 2 more field which is ```Name``` and ```PhoneNo``` I will just need to write like this ```foreach (var item in QueueNo.Concat(WaitingTime).Concat(Name).Concat(PhoneNo))``` and so on if I had more field.

Comment: @Xerillio please read carefully is not a duplicate.

Comment: So is the question, given `x` number of arrays of the same length `y`, how do you create an array of values containing `x` fields of `y` length?

Comment: @NewbieCoder Perhaps you can elaborate and explain why those are not duplicates? The question is not clear about that. Is it as Johnathan explains and as HimBromBeere answers?

Comment: what is the expected output? Is it combining two lists or a key-value pair of QueueNo and Waiting Time?

Answer (score 0):

You can [zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0) both lists together:

```
var result = QueueNo.Zip(WaitingTime, (first, second) => new { first, second });
```

Now you can `foreach` this list:

```
foreach(var e in result)
{
    var queueNo = e.first;
    var waitingTime = e.second;
}
```

Alternativly use a normal `for`-loop on one of the arrays and use the common index:

```
for(int i = 0; i < QueueNo.Length; i++)
{
    var queNo = QueueNo[i];
    var waitingTime = WaitingTime[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it. Just use `Union`

```
int[] QueueNo = {10, 20, 30, 40};
int [] WaitingTime = {1, 2, 3, 4}
var myList = QueueNo.Union(WaitingTime).ToList();
```

Comment: Be careful using `Union` with `Enumerable<int>`; it performs a set-union operation, which will discard any duplicates.