# Merge List<T> of the same Type

Tags: c#, list

I got 2 Lists whose defs are :

```
List<Type> filteredTypes = new List<Type>();
List<Type> interfaceTypes = new List<Type>();
```

When my Lists are populated I'd like to get a single loop on both of them and my idea is to merge them before "looping" so I don't have to use a LINQ (don't like it...-_-)
I checked the online doc and I think I gotta do :

```
filteredTypes.Concat(interfaceTypes);
```

I debugged as deeply as I could and my Lists are the same after the instruction...
What am I missing ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you concatenate Lists in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042219/how-do-you-concatenate-lists-in-c)

Comment: Interesting that you don't like LINQ, and yet used `Concat`, a method from System.Linq.

Comment: I was meaning lambda expressions :o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concat function `returns` a new collection, it doesn't add to the existing one.

```
var allTypes = filteredTypes.Concat(interfaceTypes);
```

Comment: this is kinda strange to me that those 2 functions have the same "architecture" but are very different... I was expecting something like Concat(filteredTypes, interfaceTypes)... The way of how the structure is looking was really seeming (to me) that filteredTypes was modified with Concat !

Comment: Most of the functions on `Enumerable` are pure functions that return new sequences, whereas most functions on `List` mutate the list -- the inconsistency between the different APIs is a consequence of C# and .NET being very big and being gradually built over the course of a decade.

Answer (score 4):

See here: [.NET List<T> Concat vs AddRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100196/net-listt-concat-vs-addrange)

the `.Concat()` call creates a new `List<T>` so you'll need something like:

```
var mergedList = filteredTypes.Concat(interfaceTypes);
```

Answer (score 3):

Concat returns a new list without modifying either of the original lists. If you want to put it in a new list do this:

```
List<Type> newList = filteredTypes.Concat(interfaceTypes);
```

If you want to put it in one of the old lists, use AddRange:

```
filteredTypes.AddRange(interfaceTypes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use AddRange?

```
 filteredTypes.AddRange(interfaceTypes);
```

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable<T>.Concat(IEnumerable<T>)` returns `IEnumerable<T>.`

Try this:

```
var resultTypes = filteredTypes.Concat(interfaceTypes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do :

```
var temp = firstList.Concat(secondList);
List<Type> finalList = temp.ToList<Type>();
```