# C#: using foreach and array element to combine 2 lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list, foreach

I have 2 lists from database for US and CA.

```
List<Order> caList = DB.GetOrderData(Countries.CA);
List<Order> usList = DB.GetOrdersData(Countries.US);
```

I want to iterate both lists into 1 list using array element "US" and "CA" with foreach loop.

```
string[] countries = {'US','CA'};
foreach(){
}
```

I was able to combine 2 lists into 1 list using `uslist.AddRange(calist)` and it works.

co-worker told me this is another way to do it using `foreach`.  I am new to IT and C#, I don't know where to start and couldn't figure it out the solution so asking fellow expert programmers for assistance to expand my c# knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: `.Concat`......

Comment: Fellow experts have answered this numerous times: [How do you concatenate Lists in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042219/how-do-you-concatenate-lists-in-c)

Comment: @ Ňɏssa: Probably didn't read my post all the way. "I was able to combine 2 lists into 1 list using uslist.AddRange(calist)" and it works.  I'm just trying to learn other ways because there is more then one solution to this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Enum.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Enum_Parse__1_System_String_) to convert the string to an enum. Use `SelectMany` to get the lists into a single enumerable stream, and `ToList` to create the list.

```
string[] countries = {'US','CA'};
var combinedList = countries.SelectMany
    ( 
        x => DB.GetOrderData(Enum.Parse<Countries>(x))
    )
    .ToList();
```

If you'd rather do it with `foreach` here's how:

```
string[] countries = {'US','CA'};
var combinedList = new List<Order>();
foreach (var country in countries)
{
    var countryCode = Enum.Parse<Countries>(country);
    combinedList.AddRange(DB.GetOrderData(countryCode));
}
```

Or

```
string[] countries = {'US','CA'};
var combinedList = new List<Order>();
foreach (var country in countries)
{
    var countryCode = Enum.Parse<Countries>(country);
    var orders = DB.GetOrderData(countryCode);
    foreach (var order in orders)
    {
        combinedList.Add(order);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, John. This is all new to me and it will definitely help me get started. Is there anyway to use `foreach` on this?

Comment: @JosephK.I've added additional examples to demonstrate the use of `foreach`.