# Filling one byte[] with multiple byte[]s

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, arrays

I created an application that stores byte arrays in my SQLiteDatabase.
This same application also selects the byte arrays from the database every 'x' seconds.

The *dataflow* of my application is as follow:

> Application - > SQLiteDatabase -> Application

**My question is:**

How do I fill one byte array with all the incoming byte arrays from the SQLiteDatabase?

**For example:**

```
Byte[] Data;
```

Needs to be filled with the following byte array:

```
Byte[] IncomingData;
```

*IncomingData* is constantly being filled by the *SQLiteDatabase*.

*Data* needs to be filled with *IncomingData* constantly.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What does "fill" mean? Do you want to concat them?

Comment: Yes, For example in string it would be like: string str1 = "12"; string str2 = "13"; if you would append them, the result would be: 1213 , I need the same thing with my byte array

Comment: Why not just use a list of bytes so?

Comment: @judgeja Yeah I'm now using a List<byte> with the .Concat function and it works!

Comment: @Mobstaa I am not sure that Concat is the best way to go. I am not sure what Linq is doing under the hood but it maybe excessivley copying things around. Compare the performance to the normal List.Add(byte b) method.

Comment: I will do some research about what the difference between .Concat and .Add is for lists EDIT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100196/net-listt-concat-vs-addrange Found this thread, the difference is that .Concat isn't modifying the list and .Add does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Concat`:

```
data1.Concat(IncomingData);
```

You'll need to add the `System.Linq` namespace reference.

Comment: I added System.Linq, when I type "data1." the intelli sense will help me with Concat, but it requires "<>" what needs to be inserted within those braces?

Comment: @mobstaa just for reference, the <> are the specified generic type

Comment: Ignore the intellisense, you **can** use it as a generic method, but you don't want to be using `<>` in your case

Comment: Okay, Thank you, I see an above answer suggested a byte list, is possible in my application too, the only problem I'm getting with using Concat is that I will need to specify the length of the array when I create it, because I will never know how big my byte array is going to be.

Comment: @Mobstaa It wouldn't compile if you were using `byte[]` without a size initializer. If you don't know the size, use `List<byte>` and you can still use `Concat` on that.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few approaches you can take.

1. Use a `List<byte>` and [`List.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)
2. Use LINQ's [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)
3. Use [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) and do it all manually

Of the three, if possible go with the `List` as it will (likely) reduce the amount of array copying required. This is what List's are made for, they use an array behind the scenes with a certain [capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx), it starts at 4 and doubles when it hits the capacity. The capacity can even be set to some large number with the `list.Capacity` property or the  constructor that takes an `int` much like you can with an array. You can always bring the list back using `List.ToArray`.

Enumerable.Concat will likely only create an array of the minimum size, meaning a new array needs to be created every time you get some more `byte`s.

Comment: Why have the overhead of converting to Lists? As you say, they use Arrays in the background anyway.

Comment: Actually it's `ToArray` not `AsArray`.

Comment: .Concat will always create a new array from the two, if this is occurring every few seconds that's a lot of copying. A list can be initialised with a capacity and is only ever copied when that capacity is reached. Yes, ToArray.