# How to merge 2 listitems

Tags: c#, merge, listitem

I have 2 listitems

1. First

   ```
   {Id = 1, Name = "a"}{Id = 2, Name = "b"}{Id = 3, Name = "c"}
   ```
2. Second

   ```
   {Id = 2, Name = "b"}{Id = 3, Name = "c"}{Id = 4, Name = "d"}
   ```

how to merge them and get a listitem like:

```
{Id = 1, Name = "a"}{Id = 2, Name = "b"}{Id = 3, Name = "c"}{Id = 4, Name = "d"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
class items {
             public  int id;
             public string name;
            }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<items>();
            list.Add(new items {id=1 , name="a"});
            list.Add(new items { id = 2, name = "b" });
            list.Add(new items { id = 3, name = "c" });

            var list1 = new List<items>();
            list1.Add(new items { id = 2, name = "b" });
            list1.Add(new items { id = 3, name = "c" });
            list1.Add(new items { id = 4, name = "d" });

            var c = list.Select(b=> new {b.id, b.name});
            var d = list1.Select(b => new { b.id, b.name });
            var merge = c.Concat(d).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var item in merge)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

           Console.ReadKey();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list1 = new[]{new {Id = 1, Name = "a"},new {Id = 2, Name = "b"}, new{Id = 3, Name = "c"}}.ToList();
var list2 = new[]{new {Id = 1, Name = "a"},new {Id = 2, Name = "b"}, new{Id = 3, Name = "c"}}.ToList();

list1.AddRange(list2);
```

Then `list1` is the merged list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "AddRange" or "Union" or "Concat" functions of  c#

e.g

```
var list1 = new[]{new {Id = 1, Name = "a"},new {Id = 2, Name = "b"}, new{Id = 3, Name = "c"}}.ToList();

var list2 = new[]{new {Id = 1, Name = "a"},new {Id = 2, Name = "b"}, new{Id = 3, Name = "c"}}.ToList();
```

then

```
var MergedResult = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

or

```
  var MergedResult = list1.AddRange(list2).ToList();
```

also you can use Concat as well...

see the difference amongst them here  [.NET List Concat vs AddRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100196/net-listt-concat-vs-addrange)