# Replace multiple InsertRange() into efficient way

Tags: c#

Inserting items to a collection,

```
MyList.Clear();
MyList.InsertRange(MyList.Count, Collection1);
MyList.InsertRange(MyList.Count, Collection2);
MyList.InsertRange(MyList.Count, Collection3);
```

In the above code, I am inserting 3 times to the same list in order to follow the sequence. Can this be replaced efficiently?

Comment: what is the type of Collection1,2,3?

Comment: 3 collections are of same type in different variable.

Comment: I meant IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T>, IList<T> etc. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is more efficient:

```
MyList.AddRange(Collection1.Concat(Collection2).Concat(Collection3));
```

If the collections are large it will probably more efficient if you prepend this line:

```
MyList = new List<string>(Collection1.Count + Collection2.Count + Collection3.Count);
```

(presumed it's a `List<string>`)

Comment: Efficiency has been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100196/net-listt-concat-vs-addrange

Answer (score 0):

To be more efficient? I don't think so. You have three distinct lists that need to be added. Each one will be iterated through when you add them. You can make the syntax a little more compact but under the hood, they will still be iterating through the three collections.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim said, the two methods seems to bem more efficient, but if you have a lot of different collections to add I would prefer the original approach with InsertRange for a better code readability.

For both InsertRange and AddRange, make sure that all collections are NOT null, or you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If any of your `Collection1,2,3` is implementing `ICollection<T>` (being `List<T>` or `T[]` for instance), then your method is optimal. If they all are just `IEnumerable<T>` then it doesn't matter - yours or single AddRange with concatenated collections.