# List<T> Concatenation dynamically

Tags: c#, dictionary, concatenation, generic-list

I am trying to concate `List<>` as follows-

```
 List<Student> finalList = new List<Student>();
 var sortedDict = dictOfList.OrderBy(k => k.Key);
 foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Student>> entry in sortedDict) {          
     List<Student> ListFromDict = (List<Student>)entry.Value;
     finalList.Concat(ListFromDict);
 }
```

But no concatenation happens. finalList remains empty. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A call to `Concat` does not modify the original list, instead it returns a new list - or to be totally accurate: it returns an `IEnumerable<string>` that will produce the contents of both lists concatenated, without modifying either of them.

You probably want to use `AddRange` which does what you want:

```
List<Student> ListFromDict = (List<Student>)entry.Value;
finalList.AddRange(ListFromDict);
```

Or even shorter (in one line of code):

```
finalList.AddRange((List<Student>)entry.Value);
```

And because `entry.Value` is already of type `List<Student>`, you can use just this:

```
finalList.AddRange(entry.Value);
```

Comment: No need for the cast - given that it's a `KeyValuePair<int, List<Student>>`, the type of `Value` is already `List<Student>`. (The cast in the OP's original code is superfluous too.)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't focus on the type first but I saw it as you were responding. It's in there now.

Comment: An additional hint: `Concat` is a LINQ extension method and all these methods use the `List<T>` as a data source, but do not change the original collection. The mentioned `AddRange` is a normal `List<T>`-method like `Add` and `Remove` and therefor alters the collection.

Answer (score 7):

Other answers have explained why `Concat` isn't helping you - but they've all kept your original loop. There's no need for that - LINQ has you covered:

```
List<Student> finalList = dictOfList.OrderBy(k => k.Key)
                                    .SelectMany(pair => pair.Value)
                                    .ToList();
```

To be clear, this replaces the whole of your existing code, not just the body of the loop.

Much simpler :) Whenever you find yourself using a `foreach` loop which does nothing but build another collection, it's worth seeing whether you can eliminate that loop using LINQ.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to read up the documentation on [`Enumerable.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894):

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   An IEnumerable that contains the concatenated elements of the two input sequences.

So you may want to use the return value, which holds the new elements.

As an alternative, you can use [`List.AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc), which *Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the List*.

As an aside, you can also achieve your goal with a simple LINQ query:

```
var finalList = dictOfList.OrderBy(k => k.Key)
                          .SelectMany(k => k.Value)
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: @downvoter care to elaborate, so that I can fix my answer?

Answer (score 3):

As specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/100206/67579), `Concat` generates a new sequence whereas `AddRange` actually adds the elements to the list. You thus should rewrite it to:

```
List<Student> finalList = new List<Student>();
var sortedDict = dictOfList.OrderBy(k => k.Key);
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Student>> entry in sortedDict) {          
    List<Student> ListFromDict = (List<Student>)entry.Value;
    finalList.AddRange(ListFromDict);
}
```

Furthermore you can improve the efficiency a bit, by omitting the cast to a `List<T>` object since `entry.Value` is already a `List<T>` (and technically only needs to be an `IEnumerable<T>`):

```
var sortedDict = dictOfList.OrderBy(k => k.Key);
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Student>> entry in sortedDict) {
    finalList.AddRange(entry.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Concat` method does not modify original collection, instead it returns brand new collection with concatenation result. So, either try `finalList = finalList.Concat(ListFromDict)` or use `AddRange` method which modifies target list.

Comment: That would have to be `finalList = finalList.Concat(ListFromDict).ToList()`, because Concat returns an `IEnumerable` of the source type, so it cannot be assigned to a list directly.