# Combining Lists using Concat

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some code that's main purpose is to combine multiple like lists into one master list to return with the View.

```
    ActivityAuditDetails searchParams = new ActivityAuditDetails();
    ActivityAuditDetails finalResults = new ActivityAuditDetails();
    List<string> finalChangedColumns = new List<string>();
    List<string> finalOldValues = new List<string>();
    List<string> finalNewValues = new List<string>();
    string finalAuditAction = string.Empty;

    List<int> auditKeys = AuditIdentityId.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
    string url = "/Audit/GetActivityAuditDetails";

    try
    {
        foreach (int auditKey in auditKeys)
        {
            searchParams.AuditIdentityId = auditKey;
            ActivityAuditDetails result =  // SOME METHOD THAT RETURNS RESULTS AS IT SHOULD;

            finalChangedColumns.Concat(result.ChangedColumns);
            finalAuditAction = result.AuditAction;
            finalOldValues.Concat(result.OldValues);
            finalNewValues.Concat(result.NewValues);
        }

        finalResults.ChangedColumns = finalChangedColumns;
        finalResults.AuditAction = finalAuditAction;
        finalResults.OldValues = finalOldValues;
        finalResults.NewValues = finalNewValues;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.ToLog();
    }
    return View(finalResults);
```

I can see that the result object is populated as it should be in the debugger.  I thought the Concat method would work to combine the lists, but my final values in the foreach loop never get update\incremented ( the list count remains zero ).

Is there another way to accomplish this, or am I having a morning brain fart?  My question was not about the differences, as I was aware of them.  I just had a momentary lapse of reason.

Comment: I think that `Concat` returns the new value,, but you don't do anything with it

Comment: What do you have to do to get an upvote?  ( Guess I should be glad I didn't get a downvote )

Comment: @mjwills Not really a duplicate, I knew the difference, I just made a mistake as to the implementation.  :-)

Comment: What the hell?  A downvote for this question, no wonder many hate using this site.  SMH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want to use `AddRange` rather than `Concat`.

The former adds the data directly to the List. The latter concatenates data into a new IEnumerable.

But because you are not assigning the result of `Concat` to anything (i.e. `var g = finalChangedColumns.Concat(result.ChangedColumns);`) your `Concat` calls do *effectively* nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100196/net-listt-concat-vs-addrange has more details.

Comment: "do basically nothing" Actually the call *does* something, but OP omits the result.

Comment: Updated for clarity @HimBromBeere .

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)` ([link to info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)) probably does what you're looking for, right?

> Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the List.

From documentation:

```
string[] input = { "Brachiosaurus", 
                   "Amargasaurus", 
                   "Mamenchisaurus" };

List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();
dinosaurs.AddRange(input);
//The list now contains all dinosaurs from the input string array
```