# linq merge 2 list of list object using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, merge

I have one list of list { {1, 3, 5}, { 2, 4, 6}}
another list of list {{7}, {8}}

Is there a quick to generate list { {1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}}

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: array1.Zip(array2, (a,b)=>a.AddRange(b))

Comment: @AryanFirouzian: No, **never do that**.  You never want the selection of a zip operator to have a side effect on one of its operands! If that's the desired effect then use a loop always, *never* `Zip`.  Remember, *queries read data*. Use a loop if you wish to *write* data.

Comment: @EricLippert can you be more accurate. This is the way we always use Zip. Is it different from your answer?

Comment: @AryanFirouzian: If that is the way that you always use zip then *you are always using it wrong*. Stop doing that!  It is extremely dangerous to use a selector as a loop. It is very easy to write a program that looks correct and works, and is extremely brittle when you make even a small change.  **Only use sequence operators to read from a sequence, never to write to it**.

Comment: @AryanFirouzian: Yes, it is **very different** from my answer.  My answer *produces a brand new sequence of fresh lists*.  Your comment *mutates existing lists*.  Producing a new value is not *writing to a member*.  Mutating an existing list is writing to a member. Again: **a query operation must never have an observable side effect on its operands**.  If you're doing that, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I got it now, you were refering to first two lines. Thanks.You are completely right.

Comment: @AryanFirouzian: I was referring to your use of `AddRange`, a side-effecting operation, inside a `Zip`, which is required to be not-side-effecting.  Use `Concat`, which is non-side-effecting.  Never use `AddRange` in a sequence operation.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that much about that.Thanks for advice. Already found  [material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100196/net-listt-concat-vs-addrange) to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have one list of list { {1, 3, 5}, { 2, 4, 6}} another list of list {{7}, {8}}
>   Is there a quick to generate list { {1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}}

Yes: use the `Zip` sequence operator.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> lists1 = whatever;
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> lists2 = whatever;
List<List<int>> zipped = lists1
  .Zip(lists2, (list1, list2) => list1.Concat(list2).ToList())
  .ToList();
```

Follow along.

- We have two sequences which contain sequences.
- Zip takes one from the first and one from the second, in pairs, and combines them
- The combination is to concatenate list2 to the end of list1.
- That gives you an `IEnumerable<int>`. We want a `List<int>`, so `ToList` it.
- The result of Zip is an `IEnumerable<List<int>>`.
- We want a `List<List<int>>`, so we `ToList` the whole thing.

This is the technique you should use when writing LINQ queries; just break everything down into a workflow of simpler steps, and then combine them together.

Comment: Where did you use lists2 ?

Comment: @AryanFirouzian: That was a typo; thanks for pointing it out! I've fixed it.

Comment: result is one list instead of two list

Comment: @Pat: The result is a single `List<List<int>>`, which contains two lists, as requested.

Comment: @Pat: Don't believe me? Run it yourself! https://dotnetfiddle.net/YstEoL